# Objective-C How to put Arrays within Arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I have multiple mock databases within my iOS application that I am making. I need one of them to be able to have a mutable array within an already mutable array. Basically, I have what are called BlockParties and within those BlockParty Objects I need a list of Trucks as one of BlockParty's attributes.

My code presently looks like this for initializing the mock database:

```
 //Initialize the mock database of block parties.
listParty = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Westside Food Truck Central" listOfTrucks: nil latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:200.1] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 146.5] schedule:@"7/15/12" ],
             [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Venice Food Truck Paradise" listOfTrucks:nil latitude:nil longitude:nil schedule:nil], 
            nil];
selectedBlockParty = nil;
```

I need the listOfTrucks attribute to be where I can have a mutable array of multiple trucks for each BlockParty. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your problem? This approach should work fine.

Comment: I need Trucks from another mock database to be within the listOfTrucks. Wasn't sure how to do that. Maybe I can just write them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   NSMutableArray *lot = [[ NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects: @"18-Wheeler", @"Dodge-Ram", @"GraveDigger" ];
   NSMutableArray *lot2 = [[ NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects: @"ShagginWagon", @"1984 F250", @"Beer Truck" ];

   listParty = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Westside Food Truck Central" listOfTrucks: lot  latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:200.1] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 146.5] schedule:@"7/15/12" ],
         [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Venice Food Truck Paradise" listOfTrucks:lot2 latitude:nil longitude:nil schedule:nil], 
        nil];
```